# Caching in wso2 esb

Tags: caching, wso2, esb

We are using wso2 as our esb layer, and we have a use case wherein we require to store login attempts of the user so what is the best way to implement this kind of caching in wso2 as cache mediator is not suitable for this purpose. And which all caching frameworks are supported by wso2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your use case is very difficult to understand, using the information given in the question. Hence, it is hard to give a comprehensive answer. So please explain a bit about your requirement.

In the meantime, I would like to add following points.

1. As you mention it might be difficult to use Cache Mediator [1] for this purpose. It mainly uses for response caching using some message hashes.
2. I think in general out of the box mediators which come with WSO2 ESB might not suitable for your requirement (Please kindly not that I'm making this statement based on my vague idea about your requirement). So sometimes you might want to write your own class mediator to suit your requirement. If you need some getting started document on how to write a class mediator [2] would be a good starting point.

So please elaborate your requirement and it will be really easy for us to give a comprehensive answer to this question.

Thanks,

Upul

[1]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Cache+Mediator

[2]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Class+Mediator

Comment: So basically we are looking for a cache component to go with the wso2 which can store the no of invalid attempts a user has made while trying to login and in case attempts become greater than 3 we are required to lock the userid.